# AEM Forms Designer - Color Mandatory Fields - Doesn't work?

Tags: pdf, adobe, aem, livecycle, xdp-pdf

I've built a bunch of these forms.    Now there is a request to indicate 'required' fields.   Fine.    (Normally I wait till the user tries to submit the form, then all fields that don't validate get colored in red.)

I've set (see image below) what I think should be done.    No effect - I built a sample form (following image) - doesn't work.

Ideas?

yes, I may be one of the 6 people left still using this tool...   :)

**Setting property for form
[image: color mandatory fields]

**Sample form - User required field not colored...**
[image: sample form - mandatory field not colored]